# ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder iterate and lookup values/table for parameters?

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, iterator

I have a module I've written in the ModelBuilder that uses a few parameters.

I need to run this module on several raster files, each time with different parameters.

Is there a way to use the iterator and some kind of lookup table?

If I were using python i would create a dict where the filename is the key, and the parameters are stored as the value.

My whole project has the structure:

1. list of 10 countries, 10 shared data source
2. cut all data sources for each country
3. perform analysis with specific parameters for each country/data source
4. repeat for each country

so a version 1 would be to put step (3) into a separate lookup table for each country, a version 2 would be to stick all of it into single lookup table for each country/file combination.

I tried googling around, looking on here, looking on the iterator docs. and i couldnt find anything

Answer (score 1):

To do this I would investigate the Model Only tool named [Iterate Row Selection](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-row-selection.htm) which:

> Iterates over rows in a table.

The table you iterate would be the lookup table of your question.